# npm alphine docker image npm modules missing

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I am trying to upgrade packages in plain `node:lts-alpine` image. `npm` command failed with missing packages.

it says `npmcli/docs` package is not found.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm # npm install
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.6.7 -> 10.1.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.1.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.1.0 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@npmcli%2fdocs - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@npmcli/docs@^1.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I removed `@npmcli/docs` from `packages.json` file and re-run the install, it says another packages is missing

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm # npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@npmcli%2fmock-registry - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@npmcli/mock-registry@^1.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

below list of packages missing from the plain image.

```
root@562e7a9c3d6f:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm# npm list
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: @npmcli/docs@^1.0.0, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: @npmcli/eslint-config@^4.0.0, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: @npmcli/mock-registry@^1.0.0, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: @npmcli/template-oss@4.14.1, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: licensee@^10.0.0, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: nock@^13.3.0, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: remark-gfm@^3.0.1, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: remark-github@^11.2.4, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: remark@^14.0.2, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: spawk@^1.7.1, required by npm@9.6.7
npm ERR! missing: tap@^16.3.4, required by npm@9.6.7
npm@9.6.7 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

How to fix this missing packages error message?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're doing this in an interactive shell in a container?  Any changes you make there will be lost as soon as the container exits.  (Correspondingly, it's rarely useful to directly run a `node` image on its own.)  Do you mean to have something like a `RUN npm ci` command in a Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am trying to fix this install issue. once I know the fix will update the steps to docker image during the build process.